# Traverse substring in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, substring

I am trying to write a method: traverseKeyAndValue(text) which will traverse a string of multiple key value pairs and print. i.e, if "key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3" is passed it will extract the key and values. 
I have used another method which substrings based on starting and ending text.
Following is my code:

```
void extractSubstring (char *source, char *dest, char *startingText, char *endingText, bool includeStart) {
     size_t sourceLen = strlen(source);
     size_t startLen = strlen(startingText); 
     size_t endingIndex = sourceLen; 
     source = strstr (source, startingText); 
     if(!includeStart){ 
        source+=startLen; 
        } 
     if(strlen(endingText)>0){ 
        endingIndex = strstr (source, endingText) - source; 
         strncpy(dest, source, endingIndex); 
     } 
     else { 
        strcpy (dest, source); 
     } 
     dest[endingIndex] = '\0';
}

void traverseKeyAndValue(char *inputText){
    int i=0;
    while(inputText[i]!='\0'){
        char key[18];
        char value[8];
        extractSubstring(inputText,key,"",":",false);
        printf(key);
        extractSubstring(inputText,value,":",",",false);
        printf(value);
        size_t keylen = strlen(key);
        size_t valuelen= strlen(value);
        int total= keylen+valuelen+1;
        inputText+=total;
    }
}
```

I have, used a pointer inputText, which I am incrementing in each iteration by the length of the key+value to point to the next entry. But this is giving "no output"

Comment: "this is not working" is not an error description, read [ask]. Also, provide a [mcve], without it your question is off-topic.

Comment: What do you have against `strtok` and other (better) allied functions?

Comment: you should run in `gdb` and do `bt` it tells where the problem is ? `gdb` telling this line  `strncpy(dest, source, endingIndex);`  doing something messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show a simple example of how to use `strtok`. I assume the input is from `fgets` (which retains any newline).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3\n"; // example input from fgets
    char seper[] = " ,:\t\n";                               // seperators
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(input, seper);
    while(tok) {
        printf("%-20s", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, seper);
        if(tok) {
            printf("%s", tok);
            tok = strtok(NULL, seper);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
key1                value1
key2                value2
key3                value3
```

There are better functions than `strtok`, which is not re-entrant, such as `strtok_r` and `strtok_s` and `strsep` depending on the platform.

The example could be improved to deal with absent value fields, but this is a basic demo.